# Wndows 10 Installation USB Updates

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-installation

Hey guys i wanted to ask: If i have an older Bootable USB with Windows(made a year ago) when i run the Setup.exe from the USB i get prompted with Updates. Are those updates stored on my PC or they were actually impelemnted in the USB and now my Windows Version from the USB is more up-to-date ?

Simply put the question is: Is there a way to update the Windows verion on a bootable USB without having to download new Windows and remake the USB install media ?

Edit: Wanted to also ask if i add other files to the USB would it cause any issues for booting the install process since i have a few GB left free on the drive.

Comment: How did you make that bootable drive? From where you downloaded Windows iso?

Comment: "Is there a way to update the Windows verion on a bootable USB without having to download new Windows and remake the USB install media" No